# Adding structure to HDF5 files - Equivalent of NetCDF "Conventions" for HDF5

Tags: hdf5, netcdf

NetCDF4 has the [Conventions](https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/conventions.html) convention for adding structure to NetCDFs. I'm looking for the analogous thing but for HDF5 specifically.

My general aim is to add structure to my HDF5 files in a *standard* way. I want to something like what HDF5 does with [images](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/ADGuide/ImageSpec.html) to define a type, using attributes on groups and datasets ~like:

```
CLASS: IMAGE
IMAGE_VERSION: 1.2
IMAGE_SUBCLASS: IMAGE_TRUECOLOR
...
```

But as far as I can tell that images specification is stand alone. Maybe I should just reuse the NetCDF "conventions"?

**Update:**

I'm aware NetCDF4 is implemented on top of HDF5. In this case, we have data from turbulence simulations and experiments not geo data. This data is usually limited to <= 4D. We use HDF5 for storing this data already, but we have no developed standards. Pseudo standard formats have just sort developed organically within the organization.

Answer (score 3):

NetCDF4 files are actually stored using the HDF5 format (http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/publications/factsheets/current/factsheet_netcdf.pdf), however they use netCDF4 conventions for attributes, dimensions, etc. Files are self-describing which is a big plus. HDF5 without netCDF4 allows for much more liberty in defining your data. Is there a specific reason that you would like to use HDF5 instead of netCDF4 ?

I would say that if you don't have any specific constraints (like a model or visualisation software that bugs on netCDF4 files) that you'd be better off using netCDF. netCDF4 can be used by NCO/CDO operators, ncl (ncl also accepts HDF5), idl, the netCDF4 python module, ferret, etc. Personally, I find netCDF4 to be very convenient for storing climate or meteorological data. There's a lot of operators already written for it and you don't have to go through the trouble of developing a standard for your own data - it's already done for you. CMOR (http://cmip-pcmdi.llnl.gov/cmip5/output_req.html) can be used to write CF compliant climate data. It was used for the most recent climate model comparison project.

On the other hand, HDF5 might be worth it if you have another type of data and you are looking for some very specific functionalities for which you need a more customised file format. Would you mind specifying your needs a little better in the comments ?

Update :

Unfortunately, the standards for variable and field names are a little less clear and well-organised for HDF5 files than netCDF since this was the format of choice for big climate modelling projects like CMIP or CORDEX. The problem essentially melts down to using EOSDIS or CF conventions, but finding currently maintained librairies that implement these standards for HDF5 files and have clear documentation isn't exactly easy (if it was you probably wouldn't have posed the question).

If you really just want a standard, NASA explains all the different possible metadata standards in painful detail here : http://gcmd.nasa.gov/add/standards/index.html.

For information, HDF-EOS and HDF5 aren't exactly the same format (HDF-EOS already contains cartography data and is standardised for earth science data), so I don't know if this format would be too restrictive for you. The tools for working with this format are described here: http://hdfeos.net/software/tool.php  and summarized here http://hdfeos.org/help/reference/HTIC_Brochure_Examples.pdf.

If you still prefer to use HDF5, your best bet would probably be to download an HDF5 formatted file from NASA for similar data and use it as a basis to create your own tools in the langage of your choice.  Here's a list of comprehensive examples using HDF5, HDF4 and HDF-EOS formats with scripts for data treatment and visualisation in Python, MATLAB, IDL and NCL : http://hdfeos.net/zoo/index_openLAADS_Examples.php#MODIS

Essentially the problem is that NASA makes tools available so that you can work with their data, but not necessarily so you can re-create similarily structured data in your own lab setting.

Here's some more specs/infomation about hdf5 for earth science data from NASA : 
MERRA product
https://gmao.gsfc.nasa.gov/products/documents/MERRA_File_Specification.pdf 
GrADS compatible HDF5 information
http://disc.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/recipes/?q=recipes/How-to-Read-Data-in-HDF-5-Format-with-GrADS
HDF data manipulation tools on NASA's Atmospheric Science Data Center : 
https://eosweb.larc.nasa.gov/HBDOCS/hdf_data_manipulation.html

Hope this helps a little.

Comment: Please see updates. I don't really like NetCDF4. It's crufty. And we are already familiar with HDF5. We are going to impose structure on our HDF5 data one way or another. I'm just looking for *standards*.

Comment: Yeah, I guess NetCDF4 isn't for everyone. I used to work with climate data so I like it (ncl has so much built in stuff), but my new lab isn't a big fan either. Please see my updated answer for more information on HDF5 standards. Unfortunately I couldn't find any nifty libraries that implement data standards for you. Plus since this is not geo data you probably don't have the same needs as climate data users like me.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 2):

The best choice for a standard really depends on the kind you data you want to store. The CF conventions are most useful for measurement data that is georeferenced, for instance data measured with a satellite. It would be helpful to know what your data consists of.

Assuming you have georeferenced data, I think you have two options:

1. Reuse the CF conventions in HDF like you suggested. There are more people looking into this, a quick Google search gave me [this](https://earthdata.nasa.gov/standards/climate-and-forecast-cf-metadata-conventions).
2. [HDF-EOS](http://www.hdfeos.org) (disclaimer, I have never used it). It stores data in the HDF files using a certain structure but seems to require an extension library to use. I did not find a specification of the structure, only an [API](http://newsroom.gsfc.nasa.gov/sdptoolkit/userguide.html). Also there does not seem to be a vibrant community outside NASA.

Therefore I would probably go with option 1: use the CF conventions in your HDF files and see if a 3rd party tool, such as [Panoply](http://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/panoply/), can make use of it.

Comment: We don't have geo data. HDF-EOS is worth a closer look though. I guess it's NetCDF's CF Conventions for HDF5?

Comment: Since you don't have geo data I would say HDF-EOS is not of much use. Also half of the CF-conventions are not applicable. Why not make an 'official' standard within the organization? You can start from scratch or start with the CF conventions, strip out what you don't need, and elaborate on that. IMO it's good to have conventions on variable names, required attributes, dimension order, dimension scales, etc.  Also a tool that checks if files are compliant could be useful.

Comment: Yeah this is exactly the path we have decided to take - within organization standard. We are taking what we can from CF Convention (we don't need much), and I'll cross reference that against HDF-EOS. We realize its unlikely we'll get everything everyone need in the first draft but we will just establish that in future people should defer to the CF Conventions first when updating the standard.